# Facebook - Send Message To Friend(s) with / or without API in PHP / cURL?

Tags: facebook

Apparently with the Facebook API, you can only read a users inbox, not send messages. Without doing a Javascript send dialog.

I am creating a simple script with twilio where I can call in, and save a message. Then have that message be emailed to a friend, or myself.

That's done, and easy, but people don't check their emails that often as they check a Facebook message.

Question:

Is it possible with the Facebook API, or using cURl or some other method in PHP to automatically login into my facebook account, and send a message to a friend?

My personal facebook, not anyone, but have my email and password passed into it and have the script do this automatically?

Is this possible, or against Facebooks TOS to have php remotely access and use my FB account?

Comment: I guess if this isn't possible, or not a good solution. I could use the FB api to make a post on their wall, and have that link to a page where they can enter a passcode to listen to the recording.

Since the recordings will be private, I'd rather do it completely privately through a FB message, but I guess this is just as good. As long as they get notified and listen to it. :)

Comment: You can build automated scripts but its again FacbooK TOS to give user name and password to any app

Answer (score 0):

If someone were looking for a similar solution today, they can request access to integrate Twilio with the Facebook Messenger API [here](https://www.twilio.com/messaging-apps).

If you send an SMS with Twilio, for example:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages

```
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages

from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient 

# put your own credentials here 
ACCOUNT_SID = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" 
AUTH_TOKEN = "[AuthToken]" 

client = TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN) 

client.messages.create(
    to="+15558675309", 
    from_="+15017250604", 
    body="Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!", 
    media_url="http://farm2.static.flickr.com/1075/1404618563_3ed9a44a3a.jpg", 
)
```

You would then be able to integrate with Facebook Messenger with little change to your Twilio code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Nimrod : https://www.nimrod-messenger.io/

Your friends will have to register and give you their API keys if you want to send messages to them.